# Css media queries not working after hosting through URL forwarding

Tags: css, media-queries, url-routing, github-pages

I hosted website on github and linked it with domain name from freenom by url forwarding.... Everything is fine with the website but Media queries of css is not working after hosting
Website link:jayeshsingh.cf 
Github page link:https://jayeshsingh9767.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your live site is loading inside the frameset

```
  <frameset rows="*">
  <frame frameborder=0 src="http://jayeshsingh9767.github.io" name="dot_tk_frame_content" scrolling="auto" noresize>
 </frameset>
```

you are loading your github hosted code inside a frameset

@media queries wont work if you are displaying site inside the frame.

Comment: So how do I can make my Live site work with domain name

Comment: you need to buy hosting space either on Github or someother hosting provider https://gist.github.com/TylerFisher/6127328